# Problema ion-progress-bar

Tags: angular, ionic, angular6, ionic-framework, ionic4

estoy intentando hacer con un tiempo ya definido que es 5 minutos, el ion-progress-bar vaya haciendo el % y se vaya viendo. El valor del value al 100% es de 1. Pero no consigo hacer-lo. Me pueden ayudar?

Componente

```
export class ProgressBarPage implements OnInit {

public progress:number = 0;
public timer:number = 0;

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.barTimer()
}

barTimer(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    this.timer = this.timer + '0.1'
  }, 1000);
}

}
```

Vista:

```
    <ion-label class="ion-margin">Default at 50%</ion-label>
    <ion-progress-bar value={{timer}}></ion-progress-bar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` se ejecuta solo una vez

`function() {...` no es la forma correcta de hacerlo siguiendo el estándar [ES6](http://es6-features.org) en su lugar usa `() => {...`

`progress: number = 0;` es redundante usa `progress = 0;` en su lugar

Te recomiendo instalar [tslint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) en tu editor de texto.

No es correcto `value="{{timer}}"` en su lugar usa `[value]="timer"` esto `{{...}}` se utiliza para agregar contenido a una etiqueta, y `[...]="..."` para mutar el valor de un parámetro de una etiqueta.

```
export class ProgressBarPage implements OnInit {

  public progress = 0;
  public timer = 0;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.barTimer();
  }

  barTimer() {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(this.timer);
      this.timer += 0.01;
      if (this.timer >= 1) {
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 100);
  }
}

<ion-label class="ion-margin">Default at 50%</ion-label>
<ion-progress-bar [value]="timer"></ion-progress-bar>
```